# Retrieving Images from Parse.com database on android but it returns null

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

On Parse.com, I have a class named **ImagesEntry** with a column named **ImageFile** that has images saved.

I have this code on android to read every row and return the images but it returns null.

```
    ParseFile[] getImagesFromParseCloudDB() {                

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "ImagesEntry");

            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            try {
                ob = query.find(); // 'List<ParseObject> ob' initialzed above OnCreate
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int i = 0;

            for (ParseObject images : ob) {
                // imagesFromDB is an array of type 'ParseFile'                
                imagesFromDB[i] = (ParseFile)images.getParseFile("ImageFile");
                i++;        
            }

            return imagesFromDB;
        }
```

Any pointers on what wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this is that `getParseFile()` doesn't request actual file. According to [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getParseFile(java.lang.String))

> function will not perform a network request

You need to add call `ParseFile.getDataInBackground()` or `ParseFile.getData()` to get actual data of the file. But don't try to spawn too many background loading tasks while iterating through array - you'll get exception if your array's size would larger than PoolSize of ExecutorService used by Parse. Consider creating some background task and  synchronous execution of `getData()` request or customizing ExecutorService for Parse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this string "_created_at" is wrong for me. In my app I have "createdAt" and works fine.

I recommend you first get all ID in a List and use my code (it works for me):

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Your_class_name");
                    query.getInBackground(imagenID, new GetCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
                            ParseObject object = (ParseObject) o;
                            ParseFile foto = (ParseFile) object.get("Your_column_name");
                            foto.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        //do things with this bytes
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al descargar la foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
```